# Sum of Timespans using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, timespan

I have a group by LINQ call and then sum the PossessionTime.Tick values as a new Timespan. This worked fine before, but now I need to keep the collection as an IQueryable instead of a List.

```
PossessionTime = new TimeSpan(x.Sum(p => p.PossessionTime.Ticks))
```

With this change I now get the following error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities.

I've looked into using `DbFunctions` but it doesn't have anything that can help I dont think.

Is my only option to move the list into memory and sum the time there?

The IQueryable is as follows:

```
return stats.GroupBy(x => x.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(a => a.Kills))
            .Select(x => new WeaponItem
            {         
                PossessionTime = new TimeSpan(x.Sum(p => p.PossessionTime.Ticks))
            });
```

I need to keep it as an IQueryable as Im using it in pagination.

Comment: Have a good look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities. The problem you are mentioning probably has little to do with the code here, but with the fact that at this time that a concrete value is needed, namely the sum, so all the lazy chain gets evaluated. Perhaps the grouping? I would not know without more code. What is the call stack?

Comment: You need to show the `IQueryable`. What is `x`? How is it defined?

Comment: Updated now @NetMage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this very easily with Linq-to-SQL/EF using straight linq becuase of `PossionTime.Ticks`.  C# DateTime operations are very limited when translating into sql operations.

If your only requirement is to support pagination, you could make it easy on yourself by doing your `WeaponItem` projection after your pagination operation and have pulled you the page into memory:

```
return stats
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(a => a.Kills))
   // paginatation
   .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
   .Take(pageSize)
   // pull paged result set into memory to make life easy
   .ToList()
   // transform into WeaponItem
   .Select(x => new WeaponItem
   {         
        PossessionTime = new TimeSpan(x.Sum(p => p.PossessionTime.Ticks))
   });
```

Alternatively, you could change your `WeaponItem` class to store `PossesionTimeTicks` and then offer `PossesionTime` as a computed property.  That might get around the restricton:

```
public class WeaponItem
{
    public long PosseionTimeTicks {get;set;}
    public TimeSpan PossesionTime {get{ return new TimeSpan(PosseionTimeticks); }
}
```

Then I think you should be able to keep your query as an IQueryable:

```
return stats
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(a => a.Kills))
    .Select(x => new WeaponItem
    {         
        PossessionTimeTicks = x.Sum(p => p.PossessionTime.Ticks)
    });
```

Comment: I think the second option will work great, thank you!

Comment: Actually the 2nd method doesn't work. I get the same error. he specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: If EF can't translate `DateTime.Ticks` then you have a couple options.  You can go with the first idea of paginating before doing the `select`.  Otherwise, there might be a way to add a "plugin" into EF that tells it how to translate `DateTime.Ticks` into sql.  Or you could update your database to always store PossesionTime as Ticks instead of in a DateTime.

Comment: Yeah the storing as ticks sounds like the only option as I need to be able to sort the iqueryable and paginated it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `TimeSpan` from HMS using `DBFunctions.CreateTime`, so you could do math to convert:

```
return stats.GroupBy(x => x.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(a => a.Kills))
            .Select(x => new WeaponItem
            {         
                PossessionTime = DBFunctions.CreateTime(0, 0, x.Sum(p => DBFunctions.DiffSeconds(p.PossessionTime, TimeSpan.Zero)))
            });
```

**Note:** I am assuming `CreateTime` will accept a seconds argument >= 60 seconds, if not, you would need to convert the sum to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: I cant do .Ticks because its an IQueryable going to entities. The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: What is the type of `PossessionTime` in database and EF? I assumed you could some `Ticks` since you accepted an answer that used `Ticks`... but now I see that didn't work.

Comment: Its timespan in the database, but I may have to change it too ticks now.

Comment: I changed the expression to use the `DiffSeconds` to compute the seconds, assuming you can pass a `TimeSpan.Zero` constant into SQL.